# Наследование в gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Я хочу научиться наследоваться в `.gitlab`. Я нашёл, как это делать в документации. Это можно делать с помощью `before_script` и `after_script`. Описано [тут](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#global-defaults). Под наследованием я понимаю возможность переиспользование кода:

```
default:
  before_script:
    - IMAGE=${IMAGE} make build
    - IMAGE=${VERSION} make run

golang-tesseract:
  when: manual
  variables:
    VERSION: test
    IMAGE: golang-tesseract
  script:
    - echo "Finished"
```

Таким образом, в данном случае, при запуске `golang-tesseract` выполнится сначала `before_script` из `default`, а затем -- `script`. При этом, переменные будут взяты из `golang-tesseract`. Но в `script` у меня остаётся одна не нужная команда. Возможно ли от неё избавиться? В документации `.gitlab` явно сказано, что в каждом правиле есть один обязательный раздел `script`. Может быть есть какие-нибудь обходные пути?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Наследование в gitlab
> Это можно делать с помощью before_script и after_script.

`before_script` и `after_script` это вовсе не про наследования, а про before и after скрипты.

Вам нужны `.job_template`, они же якоря (`anchors`), подробнее тут:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors

Решения, с примерами использования наследований:

1. Через `anchor` и `extends`:

   ```
   .pytest_template:  # это anchor, джоба с точкой в начале является якорем, от которого можно наследоваться
   script:
     - pytest $TESTS

   test_first:
     extends: .pytest_template  # это само наследование через extends свойство джобы
     variables:
       TESTS: '/first'  # в итоге выполнится скрипт "pytest /first"

   test_second:
     extends: .pytest_template
     variables:
       TESTS: '/second'  # в итоге выполнится скрипт "pytest /second"
   ```
2. Через алиасы `alias`:

   ```
   .job_template: &job_definition  # Hidden key that defines an anchor named 'job_definition'
     image: ruby:2.6
     services:
       - postgres
       - redis

   test1:
     <<: *job_definition           # Merge the contents of the 'job_definition' alias
     script:
       - test1 project

   test2:
     <<: *job_definition           # Merge the contents of the 'job_definition' alias
     script:
       - test2 project
   ```
3. Раз речь идет про скрипты, то можно наследовать даже скрипты:

   ```
   .some-script: &some-script
     - echo "Execute this script in `before_script` sections"

   .some-script-before: &some-script-before
     - echo "Execute this script in `script` sections"

   .some-script-after: &some-script-after
     - echo "Execute this script in `after_script` sections"

   job_name:
     before_script:
       - *some-script-before
     script:
       - *some-script
     after_script:
       - *some-script-after
   ```

Answer (score 0):

### !! Оба варианта не работают !!

1. Можно в базовом таске сделать `script` вместо `before_script`. Тогда в наследнике скрипт не нужен
2. Можно попробовать в наследнике сделать `script: []` (не уверен, что сработает)

### Можно вместо `default` использовать `extends`

```
.default:
  script:
    - IMAGE=${IMAGE} make build
    - IMAGE=${VERSION} make run

golang-tesseract:
  extends: .default
  when: manual
  variables:
    VERSION: test
    IMAGE: golang-tesseract
```

Comment: И в том, и в другом случае невозможно

Comment: Странно, не знал, что у них такие ограничения на `default`. Ну тогда стоит отказаться от `default` вообще и сделать через `extends`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64797697/998126